# Disabling EOF (0x1A) using SerialPort

Tags: c#, eof

I know there are other posts which have addressed this fact but I have still been unable to find a solution to my problem. 
I am received massive chunks of data from a serial port which will include 0x1A in them. I receive them in discrete chunks (at this point in chunks of 10, 18 or 528 and I know when to expect each size). The problem is that whenever I receive a 0x1A it would appear to drop this byte. 
I have tried:

```
 if (e.EventType == SerialPort.Eof) return;
```

but I get the error:
`System.IO.Ports.SerialPort` does not contain a definition for 'Eof'.

What I would like to do is simply disable this Eof feature; is it possible so that this character is no longer anything special?
Thanks in advance and sorry if this has been answered elsewhere but I haven't been able to find a straight answer anywhere...

Comment: What event handler are you in? What is `e` or `e.EventType`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course immediately after posting a question I figure it out.

I needed to use `SerialData` instead of `SerialPort`. My bad. I hope this helps other people out there!